# How do I solve gnome-shell unmet dependencies problem on ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, gnome-shell

I tried installing gnome-shell on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. But I got the following error.

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: evolution-data-server (>= 3.17.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-mutter-2 (>= 3.27.91) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed or
                           gnome-session but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: In the above question the format of warning is   "<some-package>: Depends: <other-package> (= version) but this-version is to be installed ".  And it is 8 years old question.

Comment: Did you read the answers? There is a lot of valuable information that i am sure will help in your situation even if the message is not **exactly** the same. Problem is a non-solvable dependency tree (sometimes called dependency nightmare). That usually happens when using a ppa or manually installed packages.

Comment: I got similar unmet dependencies error again, while installing `evolution-data-server`.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @kashish  I tried this before, it did not work.

Comment: I tried  `apt-get clean`, `apt-get install -f`, `apt-get update` ,`apt-get upgrade`  `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Nothing worked.

Comment: The packages available for 18.04 meet the requires in your posted message (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=evolution-data-server for `evolution-data-server`) so you could also check your sources are correct, and read & correct any messages in a `sudo apt -f install` and correct first.  (I'd likely `sudo apt update` & look for missing messages, or details there too... and have you run the `sudo apt update` recently... check your mirror is *up-to-date* maybe; ie. read & act on messages)

Comment: @guiverc  I tried, it did not work.

Comment: Did you read my last comment, ie. `sudo apt update` , are the messages appropriate, the requires ones there (your first post implies to me a source is missing and it would show with the `sudo apt update` output, with the required line not being present in output), ie. it reads like a sources issue to me, and `sudo apt update` provides the best data to peruse looking for issues (not just errors; are the appropriate detail lines output as expected? or missing?)

Comment: I ran `sudo apt update`, I did not find any problem.

Comment: `evolution-data-server` depends on `libcamel-1.2-61`. I removed this and re-installed it. After that I installed `evolution-data-server`.  Similarily, `gir1.2-mutter-2` depends on some other package. I removed it, re-installed it.  Finally, I am able to install gnome-shell.